# Kendo Scatter Chart in a div - Part of the chart invisible

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I'm using the kendo scatter chart demonstrated [HERE](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scatter-charts/index). I used it as it is in my project but it is partially hidden. It exceeds the div. How can this be fixed to make its width as same as the div's width. (Currently there is no any special styles on the div ) 
The chart is inclued below. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[kendo.resize](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo#methods-resize)** method to make sure the chart resizes with its container:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
   createChart();
   $(window).on("resize orientationchange", function () {
       throttledResize();
   });
});

var throttledResize = kendo.throttle(function () {
    kendo.resize($("#example"));
}, 100);
```

Updated [**DOJO**](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/oMaTI)

In the example, each time the window resizes or orientation is changed on mobile devices, kendo.resize is called. Additionally I am using the throttle function so resize does not happem more than once every 100 milliseconds.

Comment: This Solves the problem. Best Answer. It helped me more than I expected. Thanks